# How to generate table's data script file in SQL Server using stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

How can I generate a table's data script using a stored procedure?

I found the `bcp` utility, but it runs on the command prompt...

I need to generate table data scripts from SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: You can get some help from here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/715ccb74-f215-4242-9ce2-0c1563e67ac8/generate-table-create-scripts-using-stored-procedure?forum=sqlexpress

Comment: Do you need to generate only data or table structure too?

Comment: thank you #B Pavan Kumar . But generates table structure only...

Comment: simple table data....

Answer (score 0):

To prepare script you can use that query

```
declare @data nvarchar(max) 
set @data =  'insert into table2 (list of columns) '

select top 100 @t = @t+ char(13) +' select '''+convert(nvarchar(100), col1)+''' as col1 ,'''+convert(nvarchar(100),col2)+''' as col2 union'
from table1

select @data
```

I think you can use `SP_EXECUTESQL` to run `@data` script in procedure.